# How does iOS Swift Runtime work

Tags: ios, swift, runtime

In `ObjC`, it is using `Messaging`, `static binding`, `dynamic typing`, `dynamic binding`, `dynamic method resolution`, `dynamic loading`, `introspector` and so on.

Importantly, the core method `objc_msgSend` is responsible for taking the selector you're sending and the object you're sending it to, and looking that up in the class method tables to figure out exactly which piece of code is supposed to handle it.

My concerns here are:

1. Is `Swift` doing something similar like `ObjC` on runtime?
2. How does `Swift runtime` find the implementation code for some object/class method?
3. In `ObjC`, `classes` and `objects` are compiled to some `runtime types` such as `C struct` on runtime. Then what are such `classes` and `objects` compiled to on runtime in `Swift`?
4. Does `Swift runtime` have something like `class / meta class / isa pointer / super pointer`?

Comment: Can you give an example?

Comment: @Boris What I answered is related to  #1 & #2. Regarding #3 & #4 I'm sure that Swift definitely has something but that's not stabilized. Initially there were plans to stabilize ABI in Swift 3.0 release, but planes are changed: https://www.infoq.com/news/2016/05/swift-3-no-stable-abi

Answer (score 44, accepted):

In short there are Dynamic and Static types of method call dispatching.

1. Static - the function address to be called is determined in the compilation time, so that expense of such call is similar to C-function calling. This mechanism is used for `private` methods or `final` classes methods call dispatching.
2. Dynamic dispatching is mechinism which allows to implement polymorphism concept of OOP - the function address to be called is determined in running time. Swift has two subtypes of it:

   2.1. Obj-C - you already described in the question. This mechanism is used when object inherits from NSObject or calling method has @objc prefix.

   2.2. Virtual table based (like in C++) - there is similar witness tables. What it does during method call dispatching is just single arithmetic operation - calculation of actual function address based on function  offset in the base class witness table and the object class witness table location. So that's a relatively cheap operation comparing to Obj-C. It explains why "pure" Swift approximates to C++ performance.

If you don't mark you method with `private` keyword or your class is not `final` and same time you class is "pure" Swift (it does not inherit NSObject) then this virtual table based mechanism is used. It means that all the methods by default are `virtual`.

P.S.
Helpful link for proving my vision regarding "Types":

https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=27

"Subtypes" explanation is based on my understanding.

Comment: Nice explanation. Doesn't static marked methods runtime is also static?